# reporting to two Google Analytics profiles using AddThis config - data_ga_property

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, social-networking, addthis, web-analytics

I am using the AddThis widget include to display the social buttons on my site. I wish to be able to track clicks with Google Analytics, and the [documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381260-google-analytics-integration#.UDNtaqPTCik) appears to support this. However, I would like to activity to *two* different profiles.

The `addthis_config` appears to only take one `data_ga_property` value, which means I can't report to my local and global GA profiles.

Is there a way to report to two profiles?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var addthis_config = {
                           data_ga_property: 'UA-18721873-1',           
                           data_ga_social: true
                          };
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/25/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-hsakjdhsakjdhkjsdhakjdshkjdh"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try passing an array or object of the UA numbers? I'm going to try that.

Comment: I tried passing an array of UA IDs, and it silently failed on all of them.

Comment: @changokun No, I didn't try that. I ended up abandoning the functionality as addThis don't seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

By default all profiles under an account will receive all data to the account that is not filtered via the filters administrative tab in GA.

You don't have to do anything to make what you want happen unless you've done something to purposely stop it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I know that if you want to report _anything_ to two different profiles in Google Analytics then you have to make two requests - one for each profile. This would appear to be the case with addThis too. Although addThis have a `addthis_config` variable, they don't appear to support reporting to more than one profile.